# Angular 2 Dropdown List Conditional Elements

Tags: angular

A list of results is returned each with a different status value between 1 and n.
Example:

ID  CurrentStatusID MaxStatusID

1,   2, 5

2,  2,  3

3,  5,  -

The status is from a select dropdown field with a list from which contains

aStatusID   aStatusName

1,  pending

2,  under review

3,  provisionally accepted

4,  accepted

5,  completed

Each result in the results has a select field to change the status
The status can only be changed to a value less than the Max Status ID of the record (the select dropdown uses the following code)

```
 <select name="aStatus" id="aStatus" class="form-control" 
(change)="cAStatus($event,ticket.tRID)" required>
<option *ngFor="let aStatus of aStatusList"
[ngValue]="aStatus.aStatusID"
          [selected]="ticket.aStatus.trim() === aStatus.aStatusName.trim()?'selected':''">{{aStatus.aStatusName}}
          </option>
</select>
```

How can the options greater than or equal to the Max StatusID of the record be greyed out?
Example

Record ID 1 would in the dropdown list show aStatusID 5 greyed out

Record ID 2 would in the dropdown list show aStatusID 3, 4, & 5 greyed out

Record ID 3 would in the dropdown list show all aStatusID selectable

Comment: how is this java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the disabled attribute of the option.

E.g.

```
 <select name="aStatus" id="aStatus" class="form-control"  required>
<option *ngFor="let aStatus of aStatusList"
          [ngValue]="aStatus.aStatusID"
          [selected]="ticket.aStatus.trim() === aStatus.aStatusID.trim() ?'selected':''"
          [disabled]="ticket.aMaxStatusId && ticket.aMaxStatusId !== '-' && aStatus.aStatusID.trim() >= ticket.aMaxStatusId.trim()">{{aStatus.aStatusName}}
</option>
</select>
```

The above solution has a check for a max status of '-'.
If the maxStatus is instead ' ' or not provided, you can leave out the check and simply have:

```
<option *ngFor="let aStatus of aStatusList"
  [ngValue]="aStatus.aStatusID"
  [selected]="ticket.aStatus.trim() === aStatus.aStatusID.trim() ?'selected':''"
  [disabled]="ticket.aMaxStatusId?.trim() && aStatus.aStatusID.trim() >= ticket.aMaxStatusId.trim()">{{aStatus.aStatusName}}
</option>
```

Hope this is helpful.